# Why does SonarQube not show results, although the analysis succeeded?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I use sonar-runner to analyse my project and the analysis succeeds:

```
14:30:34.813 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 160ms
14:30:34.813 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/AMLServerProj
14:30:34.813 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
14:30:34.814 DEBUG - Post-jobs : 
14:30:34.815 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@3335ebfc[id=1,key=AMLServerProj,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-AMLServerProj
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 53.958s
Final Memory: 26M/788M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I navigate to http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/AMLServerProj I get this error message:

```
No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration.
```

This is my error log:

```
2015.08.03 20:47:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.c.ComputationService] Analysis of project AMLServerProj (report 2) (done) | time=7880ms
2015.08.03 20:47:01 ERROR web[o.s.s.c.ComputationThread] Failed to process analysis report 2 of project AMLServerProj
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.core.issue.db.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #2) failed. 1 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xA3\xBA\xB1\xEF\xBF...' for column 'message' at row 107
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.core.issue.db.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #2) failed. 1 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xA3\xBA\xB1\xEF\xBF...' for column 'message' at row 107
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:177) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:169) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:61) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.commit(BatchSession.java:177) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.increment(BatchSession.java:214) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.insert(BatchSession.java:134) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistIssuesStep.execute(PersistIssuesStep.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ComputationService.process(ComputationService.java:89) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ComputationContainer.execute(ComputationContainer.java:47) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ComputationThread.run(ComputationThread.java:58) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.core.issue.db.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #2) failed. 1 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xA3\xBA\xB1\xEF\xBF...' for column 'message' at row 107
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:127) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:114) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.commit(BaseExecutor.java:201) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.commit(CachingExecutor.java:104) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:174) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xA3\xBA\xB1\xEF\xBF...' for column 'message' at row 107
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1603) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1268) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:103) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xA3\xBA\xB1\xEF\xBF...' for column 'message' at row 107
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1564) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

This is my `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.projectKey=AMLServerProj
sonar.projectName=AMLServerProj5.1
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I was successful。
I changed the sonar-project.properties
sonar.sourceEncoding=GBK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be 2 explanations for this:

- You browsed the Web application too rapidly, the server did not have the time to process your analysis. As the log says: `"Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report."`
- If you think that you've waited already for too long, maybe the processing of your analysis on server-side went wrong. In this case, there are 2 ways to check this:

  - In the "Settings > System > Analysis Reports > Past Reports" administration page, you should be able to see that the processing failed
  - In the server logs, you should have a error message that gives more details about the failure

Comment: Dear Fabrice, I believe that I have bullet2 probem which claims waited already. When I look up ErrorDetails section I got 'Unable to load component class okhttp3.OkHttpClient' exception and I google it but I cannot find any solution.

Comment: @user3751548 I'm getting the same 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient' exception. Were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: Where to find these settings:- `Settings > System > Analysis Reports > Past Reports`? @user3751548

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't find any failed background tasks or error logs and wonders why Sonar does not show results if test was successful - just check what is your `sonar.analysis.mode`. It should be `publish`, because `preview` and `issues` does not send results to Sonar.

In our case we created integration (results were visible in Sonar), then configured integration with [Gitlab plugin](https://gitlab.talanlabs.com/gabriel-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin) which forced us to change analysis mode to `preview`. Then our results were not visible in Sonar even if test was successful - I didn't realize that connection because it was first time when I used Sonar and.. it was late ;-)

Now we run Sonar analysis 2 times, one for Sonar server results, one for Gitlab autoreview.