# SonarQube Scanner not sending result to SonarQube after executing in a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, analysis

After SonarQube Scanner was executed by a Jenkins job, the analysis result is not being uploaded to the SonarQube server:

```
00:15:23.616 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
00:15:23.621 DEBUG: Post-jobs : GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher (wrapped)
00:15:23.621 INFO: Executing post-job GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher (wrapped)
```

In one of my other Jenkins jobs, the result is actually uploaded to SonarQube with this log which is not found for above case:

```
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
INFO: 20 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 46 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 312ms, dir size=1 MB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 227ms, zip size=561 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 256ms
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: first of all, how do you run the job on jenkins? do you use the jenkins scanner, or do you use any other build tool like maven or ant? If so, have you tried to increase the output of that build step. eg. for gradle providing `-i` for more output? - it is hard to tell, from your description what the actual problem might be. because jenkins does not tell us anything at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44719818/7184761

I found that was because of github configuration that forced value of "sonar.analysis.mode" to be "issues"(to send to github), not "publish"(to send to sonarqube server)